# Javascript: Make an object call an inputted function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm working on a much bigger project but when this didn't work there I made simple version, to see if it works, but it doesn't. This is the simplified code:

```
a = new Thing(sayHi);

function sayHi() {
    alert("hi");
}

function Thing (callback) {
    callback;
}
```

What I wanted was that when a `Thing` was created, the function `sayHi()` was called but that doesn't work. Why is that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only mentioning the callback function, not *calling* it. Instead:

```js
a = new Thing(sayHi);

function sayHi() {
    alert("hi");
}

function Thing (callback) {
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call your function. Use `callback();` instead of `callback;`

Answer (score 0):

A reference to function sayHi is been passed but not been invoked anywhere. You have to invoke the callback as

callback.call();